# subscript and italic in sns

Tags: python, seaborn, subscript, italic

I'm trying to use subscripts and italic in the y label in sns, this is what I would like to write:

[image]

This is the code I am using, but the 1/2 is not in italic and subscript. Any advice?

```
#ax2.set(ylabel=r'$g_s{t}$') 
ax2.set(ylabel=' $g_s$ t\u2081/\u2082')
```

[image: this is what I get now (sorry it is a screenshot from the ylabel]

Thank you in advance

Comment: I have almost no experience with Seaborn or Tex, but looking at this example, it looks like it should be `'$t_gs1/2$'`. **Edit**: After a quick bit of research, it looks like it needs delimiters: `t_{gs1/2}`.

Comment: Just use `$t_{gs1/2}$`

Comment: https://wch.github.io/latexsheet/